# Working with special characters in VBScript and XMLHTTP

Tags: vbscript

With this VB Script code execute download the XLSX file from autorized remote share to my client server.

The name of XLSX file is

> TB-àdemain20180703.xlsx

For the special character **à** on the file name **TB-àdemain20180703.xlsx** the download is failed because on the client server the XLSX File is saved with this name :

> TB-Ã demain20180703.xlsx

How to do resolve this ?

My code below.

```
Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

File.Open "GET", "https://share.xxx.com/Report/TB-àdemain20180703.xlsx", False

File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
File.Send

Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
BS.type = 1
BS.open
BS.Write File.ResponseBody
BS.SaveToFile "D:\Report\TB-àdemain20180703.xlsx", 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your link.

Please replace this :

```
File.Open "GET", "https://share.xxx.com/Report/TB-àdemain20180703.xlsx", False
```

With

```
File.Open "GET", "https://share.xxx.com/Report/TB-%C3%A0demain20180703.xlsx", False
```

I hope I was helpful.